# Length to Size in MB

Tags: c#, string

I know there is the strlen or length property of a string or stringbuilder. is there any way i can compute the length of the string and display or expose the size of a particular string? (e.g 
if (string = length of 200) then (String = 20KB or MB)

Comment: To perhaps be more clear, you need to determine how many bytes are used to represent the string.  Some encodings using 1 byte per character (ASCII) while others use 2 bytes per character (UNICODE).  Once you have the number of bytes, divide by 1024 to get KB.  Divide by 1024 again to get MB.

Comment: So lets say i have 200 characters in my string i would do this computation?

200/1024(Result in KB)
result of Kb/1024 (result in MB)?

Comment: Yes, assuming that each character is represented by 1 byte.  Have a look at this MSDN link to get an idea of the built-in encodings that are available.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

To get the size in megabytes specifically:

```
decimal megabyteSize = ((decimal)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(str) / 1048576);
```

Where `str` is the string you want to check.

Comment: Much Thanks fOr all of your advice. i will try all of your suggestions tommorrow!

Best Regards,